# CSS hover grid box with 2 different background colors at once

Tags: html, css

I would like to hover my grid box, which includes both an image section as well as the description. The problem lies in their backgrounds. I've provided two separate backgrounds for this box, as the description section features a different background.

If I hover it, the background changes everywhere into the one color, which I set in the code.

My code looks as per below:

```css
.grid1 {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px white solid;
  transition: border 0.5s;
}

.grid1:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #f9fafc;
}

.grid1 img {
  width: 98%;
  height: 275px;
  object-fit: contain;
  filter: brightness(99.3%);
  margin-left: 1%;
  filter: blur(1px) grayscale(1) opacity(75%);
}

.grid1:hover img,
.grid1:hover .companyname {
  filter: none;
  filter: brightness(99.3%);
  color: black;
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg">
  <div class="companyname">
    <p>us</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the result underneath:

[image]

I would like to keep the white background for my whole box and change only the description background. How can I do it in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you want the user to be able to hover anywhere on the grid and change the background for the div, which you already do using `.grid1:hover .companyname`

But you don't want it to alter the background of the image div as well.

This snippet removes the .`grid1:hover img`

```css
.grid1 {
  background: #fdfdfd;
  height: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px white solid;
  transition: border 0.5s;
}

.grid1:hover {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #f9fafc;
}

.grid1 img {
  width: 98%;
  height: 275px;
  object-fit: contain;
  filter: brightness(99.3%);
  margin-left: 1%;
  filter: blur(1px) grayscale(1) opacity(75%);
}

/*.grid1:hover img,*/
.grid1:hover .companyname {
  filter: none;
  filter: brightness(99.3%);
  color: black;
  background: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg">
  <div class="companyname">
    <p>us</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! This is exactly what I wanted here. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if by description you mean that "us" text below but if that is the case, I think you want something like this:

```css
.grid1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 80%;
}

.companyname {}

.companyname:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
  <div class="companyname">
    <p>Company</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, select the element and edit the hover options in CSS using `.companyname:hover`.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please insert codelines directly as minimal reproduciable code snippet (ctrl + m). If the link of a fiddle changes, getting deleted or the content changes, the question or anwser would hold no furtehr value to the community. As such a fiddle may only be used to accompany an existing codesnippet but not to replace it completely.

Comment: OK, than you for your hint. This is my second post so far. I will try to use Fiddle and Codepen in the future. Rgds,

Comment: It's not an answer really. Your solution leads to hover the text description only, whereas I need to hover everything bounded at once (everything in the box), keeping the box background the same as it is and hovering only the text description background.

Comment: Hello, my solution was meant to hint you in the right direction, it's not a 100% working solution for your case. If you want to use CSS only, try `.parent:hover .child, .parent.hover .child { change background here }`. Also, you can do this very easily with some vanilla JS.